# Auto setting properties in C#

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I have a class called Place that uses getters and setters like so:

```
public class Place
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public GeoCoordinate Location
    {
        set
        {
            // geocode Address field and receive Geocoding response, initializing a new instance of GeoCoordinate class - my attempt below..
            IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder();
            IEnumerable<Address> matchedAddresses = geocoder.Geocode(this.Address);
            this.Location = new GeoCoordinate(matchedAddresses.Cast<Address>().First().Coordinates.Latitude, matchedAddresses.Cast<Address>().First().Coordinates.Longitude);
        }
        get
        {
            return this.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

And say I want to create a new instance of the class Place like so:

```
    Place thePlace = new Place()
    {
        Address = "123 Fake Street, London"
    };
```

How would I automatically trigger the setter for the Location variable when the Address property is set so that the address fed in is automatically geocoded and the GeoCoordinate object is set automatically?

Comment: You're going to have to change `Address` to not be an auto property. The setter would simply set the `Location` property also.

Comment: It is! I haven't tackled this yet.. First attempt!

Comment: You've got a problem with your Location property - you are recursively calling both get and set with the code that you have. Did you mean to back it with a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to change the `Address` from an auto-property to a "regular" one (i.e. a property composed from a variable and a getter/setter pair), like this:

```
private string address;
public string Address {
    get {return address;}
    set {
        // Prepare the location
        GeoCoordinate loc = GetGeoCoordinateFromAddress(value);
        // Store address for future reference
        address = value;
        // Setting the location by going through the property triggers the setter
        Location = loc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you! And is what I'm trying to do considered good design?

Comment: @adaam, I claim your semantic is off, as assigning the Location property will not do remotely what you would expect. I would personally redesign at least that piece.

Comment: @adaam The problematic thing in your code is that the setter of `Location` ignores the `value` being sent to it. You may be able to improve upon it by separating out the code that searches `matchedAddresses` for the `Location` into a separate method, or removing the `Location` setter altogether, moving the logic into the setter of the `Address` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change `public string Address { get; set; }` to

```
private string _address;
public string Address
{
    get { return _address; }
    set
    {
        // code to set geocoder
        _address = value;
    }
}
```

By the way, this code here

```
public GeoCoordinate Location
{
    ...
    get
    {
        return this.Location;
    }
}
```

will recurse forever. You should think about reworking that.

Answer (score 1):

The `set` semantic doesn't make any sense for what you are doing (you aren't even using the `value` keyword). At worst, it makes this code nonsense:

```
obj.Location = someGeoCoordiante;
```

You could easily just put the logic in the `get` piece (and not define a `set`). Of course this will re-run your calculation every time you access it. If that is a problem, still remove the set and have the setter for the `Address` property recalculate the locally stored `Location` field.